# Returning posgreSQL database records with user input

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am faced with a blocker in my `Node/express` application.

I want to return data from a **postgresSQL** database table, but doing that with the query parameter passed by a user...

#### Assume the following:

- db is a postgresSQL database pool connection.
- Trips table is already created and populated with trips having their destination value as **"Nigeria"**.

Below is my model and controller code.

model.js

```
const getTrips = async ( column, value )=> {
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM trips WHERE $1 = $2';

  const { rows } = await db.query ( query, [value] );

  return rows;
}
```

controller.js

```
const getTrips = async ( req, res) => {
  const { destination } = req.query;

   const result = await Trips.getTrips( 'destination' destination );

   console.log( result.length )
}
```

#### Issue am faced with

`Url = http://.../?destination="Nigeria"`

When I pass the `destination` query parameter from the user directly , like this `Trips.getTrips('destination', destination )`, an empty array is returned.

However if the string equivalent of the query parameter value is passed, like this `Trips.getTrips('destination', 'Nigeria')`, an array with the Trips matching Nigeria as destination is returned.

#### Checks have done

- `console.log(typeof destination) // returns string.`
- `console.log (destination) // returns "Nigeria"`

#### Question

1. Why is passing the parameter directly not returning the appropriate records and passing its string equivalent returns appropriate records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking away the quotes in your URL query (`Url = http://.../?destination=Nigeria`). It seems like you're querying for `"Nigeria"` literally (quotes included). Does this help?

Comment: Ok. Would try that.

Comment: Specifically when constructing the URL on the client you should use something like: `url = 'http://.../?destination=' + encodeURIComponent(destination)`